# php echo and backslashes

Tags: php, echo

For life of me I can not get this working...

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<a href=\"concert.php?id=. $row["id"] .\">. $row["date"] .</a>"
"<br>";
}
```

This is the error...

> syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

I believe you just add escapes to html "?

Comment: `. $row["id"] .` => `". $row["id"] ."` or `"id={$row['id']}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some closing and opening quotes. Replacing some of those double quotes with single quotes will remove the need for those backslashes as well.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<a href="concert.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["date"] . '</a><br>';
    }
```